# Magento2 : How to get quantity as dropdown for configurable product in cart page

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product

In default.phtml

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
    $qty = $productStockObj->getQty();
   ?>
   <div class="field qty">
<select id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty" name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" data - cart - item -
        id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $_item->getSku() ?>">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if ($i == $block->getQty()) {
            echo 'selected';
        } ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
 </div>
```

for simple products only showing dropdown with quantity, for configurable products how to get child products quantity to show in dropdown

Comment: any idea about that

Comment: yes, need to change in js file